# Why is git clean is not removing a specific file?

Tags: git

I have a file in my project that was present in previous commits, and then was removed by a later commit. I wanted to use `git clean` to remove the file, but it wouldn't do it. I used the workaround of just `rm`ing the file, but I'm wondering:

Why would `git clean` not see this file as a candidate for deletion?

---

Here's the (sanitized) trace of my experiments:

```
me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 64a87ed Merge branch 'dev/phrogz/whee' into 'master'

me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../app/faux/prep.sh

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git clean -n
me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git clean -f -d
me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../app/faux/prep.sh

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

me@mybox:/myproj/build$ rm ../app/faux/prep.sh 
me@mybox:/myproj/build$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: `cd .. ; git clean -n` or perhaps `git clean -n ..`

Comment: It's an answer that I didn't want to pad out to a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [help for git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) says "Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, **starting from the current directory**." (emphasis mine)

So since the file is in `../app` you need to go up one level before the command will try to remove it.